# jquery hide and show html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have an html sidebar page.I just want to make when I click the each section show their posts.I tried to make it but It's continuous hiding.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="list-group">

                <a href="#section-1" id="section-1" class="list-group-item">Döküman 1 </a>
                <a href="#section-2" id="section-2" class="list-group-item">Döküman 2</a>
                <a href="#section-3" id="section-3" class="list-group-item">Döküman 3</a>
                <a href="#section-4" id="section-4" class="list-group-item">Döküman 4</a>
                <a href="#section-5" id="section-5" class="list-group-item">Döküman 5</a>
                <a href="#section-6" id="section-6" class="list-group-item">Döküman 6</a>
                <a href="#section-7" id="section-7" class="list-group-item">Döküman 7</a>
                <a href="#section-8" id="section-8" class="list-group-item">Döküman 8</a>
                <a href="#section-9" id="section-9" class="list-group-item">Döküman 9</a>
                <a href="#section-10" id="section-10" class="list-group-item">Döküman 10</a>
                <a href="#section-11" id="section-11" class="list-group-item">Döküman 11</a>
                <a href="#section-12" id="section-12" class="list-group-item">Döküman 12</a>
                <a href="#section-13" id="section-13" class="list-group-item">Döküman 13</a>
                <a href="#section-14" id="section-14" class="list-group-item">Döküman 14</a>
                <a href="#section-15" id="section-15" class="list-group-item">Döküman 15</a>
                <a href="#section-16" id="section-16" class="list-group-item">Döküman 16</a>
                <a href="#section-17" id="section-17" class="list-group-item">Döküman 17</a>
            </div>
        </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
        $("p").hide();
        // shows the slickbox on clicking the noted link
             $('#section-1').click(function() {
             $("p").show('fast');
        return false;
              });
             // hides the slickbox on clicking the noted link
             $('#section-1').click(function () {
                 $("p").hide('fast');
                 return false;
             });

    });
</script>

     <div class="row" >
                         <h3>Head</h3>
                         <p id="maincolumn" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nec lacus non massa maximus gravida. Etiam gravida arcu et dui pretium, at cursus tellus sollicitudin. Aliquam porta quam at tellus mattis gravida. Aenean quis augue vitae ante consequat auctor sed sed tellus. Etiam finibus, libero condimentum semper rutrum, lorem dolor bibendum velit, quis dapibus lectus eros consectetur odio. Pellentesque arcu lacus, semper quis justo quis, lacinia convallis enim. Fusce suscipit nibh non lacus consequat sollicitudin. Morbi accumsan, massa vitae pretium aliquet, leo nisi lobortis magna, eget ullamcorper massa diam sit amet mauris. Suspendisse mattis enim et accumsan euismod.

Nam vestibulum, orci et hendrerit pretium, odio elit fermentum dolor, vitae sodales ligula justo vitae turpis. Integer ut feugiat tortor. Donec pretium velit id orci efficitur tristique. Etiam eget tincidunt arcu. Phasellus placerat diam vel mi pulvinar imperdiet. Nullam eget maximus tortor. Sed tempor lacinia sagittis. Praesent et massa et mi ornare eleifend. Nulla ut pretium ex. Nullam id mattis eros. Aliquam vel justo tellus. Nam scelerisque facilisis arcu a accumsan. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent porttitor odio sed augue vehicula, nec facilisis nunc egestas. Cras velit massa, maximus eget luctus ac, tincidunt eget sem.</p>
                     </div>
```

I write a jquery like this but I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your markup little bit:

```
<a href="#section-1" id="section-1" class="list-group-item">Döküman 1 </a>
<a href="#section-2" id="section-2" class="list-group-item">Döküman 2</a>
<a href="#section-3" id="section-3" class="list-group-item">Döküman 3</a>
 ... other as is
```

but you can make a class name as per anchor belongs to any div or the element you want to show/hide:

```
<div class='hide section-1'>Döküman 1</div>
<div class='hide section-2'>Döküman 2</div>
<div class='hide section-3'>Döküman 3</div>
...and so on
```

then you can use this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.list-group a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.hide').hide();
        $('.'+this.id).show();
    });

});
```

#### [Demo as per above changes.](http://plnkr.co/edit/PNwYiZOtmerTNPF5A2jl?p=preview)

---

or as per your markup, you can change a little:

```
<a href="#maincolumn1" id="section-1" class="list-group-item">Döküman 1 </a>
<a href="#maincolumn2" id="section-2" class="list-group-item">Döküman 2</a>
<a href="#maincolumn3" id="section-3" class="list-group-item">Döküman 3</a>
 ... other as is
```

also you can change here:

```
<p id="maincolumn1">The content.</p>
<p id="maincolumn2">The content.</p>
<p id="maincolumn3">The content.</p>
```

then you can use this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.list-group a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.row p').hide();
        $(this.getAttribute('href')).show();
    });

});
```

#### [Demo as per above changes.](http://plnkr.co/edit/kr9EgPXYWCm9YjLABtCb?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I did not found any issue in your code. I think you forgot to add main jquery file.
Try this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
        $("p").hide();
        // shows the slickbox on clicking the noted link
             $('#section-1').click(function() {
             $("p").show('fast');
        return false;
              });
             // hides the slickbox on clicking the noted link
             $('#section-1').click(function () {
                 $("p").hide('fast');
                 return false;
             });

    });
</script>
```